# Is it possible to get notified (e.g. email) when a user purchases a subscription?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have an Android App published on Google Play Store. I implemented In-App purchase in the app with one subscription.

Uses have started purchasing the subscription so, I was wondering if I can get an email notification whenever a user purchased the subscription. I am aware of the [Google real-time developer notification](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications) but it requires backend API to be modified (and it's not free).

I was hoping for Google Play Console settings which would do just this. If this is not possible then I would like to know how you get notified of new purchases (code).

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain this event in callback and send email to your adress programmatically.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. I am going to use SendGrid for that. I was just wondering whether Google provided some settings for that unfortunately they don't allow it directly.